# How to filter a value exactly equal to a given input in react-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-table

I am using built-in setFilter function of react table here. Second argument is the value with which each input category will be match but not exactly. For example if we have two categories Govt and Non-govt and I have to filter Govt. But It is filtering Govt as well as Non-govt because the word Govt is present in the word Non-govt.
What should I do now?

```
const tableInstance = useRef(null);
  const filterTests = (criteria) => {
    if (tableInstance.current) {
      tableInstance.current.setFilter('test_category', criteria.category);
      tableInstance.current.setFilter('test_state', criteria.state);
      tableInstance.current.setFilter('test_client', criteria.client);
      tableInstance.current.setFilter('test_name', criteria.name);
    }
  };
```

and I'm calling filterTests table in  another component:

```
const handleFilter = () => {
    let criteria = {};
    criteria.category = category;
    criteria.state = state;
    criteria.client = client;
    criteria.name = name;
    filterTests(criteria);
  };
```

My columns file's data is:

```
export const columns = [
  {
    id: 'test_name',
    Header: 'NAME',
    accessor: 'name',
  },
  {
    id: 'candidate_site_blocked',

    Header: `BLOCK
CANDIDATE SITE
  REGISTERATION`,
    accessor: 'block_candidate_site_registration',
  },
  {
    id: 'admin_site_blocked',

    Header: `BLOCK
ADMIN SITE
  REGISTERATION`,
    accessor: 'block_admin_site_registration',
  },

  {
    id: 'delete_test',

    Header: '',
  },
  {
    id: 'test_category',
    accessor: 'category',
  },
  {
    id: 'test_state',
    accessor: 'state',
  },
  {
    id: 'test_client',
    accessor: 'client',
  },
];
```

Comment: can you share minimal working example .

Comment: Code is distributed in multiple files so it would be very tough to share a working example. I just want to ask how can we filter with exact value instead of substring in setFilter method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the respective column object:

```
 {
    id: 'your_column_id',
    accessor: 'your_accessor',
    filter: (rows, id, filterValue) =>
      rows.filter((row) => filterValue === '' || row.values[id] === filterType)
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

{
id: 'your_column_id',
accessor: 'your_accessor',
filter: 'equals',
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: good answer - works - but I can't find this properly documented anywhere !  I have found example code that uses filter: 'includes' for partial matching too, but only in example code not actually written down for reference

Comment: thank you it is working file for my side i only this one`filter: 'equals'`

Comment: Here is filters documented:
https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/features/filters